# How to create a second personal folder in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pop3

When I create a new data file through the Data File Managment menu option, the folder is created with only the **Deleted Items** and **Junk E-mail** folders.

How can I have it create the sent items, inbox, outbox, etc folders? Do I have to manually add them?

I want to associate a different pop3 e-mail account with it, if I create them manually, will the sent items move to that folder by default?

I suspect there has to be an option for creating it with those folders automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I closed outlook, opened it again, and all the folders were there